# Android HttpClient reactive authentication

Tags: android, http-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to set up an Android app where I can access URL's behind arbitrary proxies or HTTP authentications.  That is, the app won't know immediately if a URL needs authentication and will repond to an authentication request by asking the user for credentials, the same way it does for the Android Browser.

I recently worked out [how to request user authentication for a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106769/http-proxy-in-android-emulator-works-for-browser-not-for-webview), responding to authentication requests from the browser, bringing up a dialog, and advancing the user to the destination page.  I am looking to do the same with `HttpClient`.

The basic process, as I see it, is to:

1. Perform the request via `HttpClient.execute`.

   - If not 401 or 407 with proper headers, trigger a "done" callback.
   - Otherwise...
2. Pop up a dialog asking for the username and password.
3. Set the http credentials in the HTTP client via `HttpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials`.
4. Return to step 1 until the the user clicks cancel or the server gives up.  In that case, trigger a "failed" callback with the last response received.

Am I on the right track or has someone already implemented something similar?  I would hate to be reinventing the wheel on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reactive approach described above did work.  Responding to an arbitrary 401 or 407 request is effective with the caveat that you need to suppor each authentication scheme you expect to encounter so something like `UsernamePasswordCredentials` won't work for NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [authentication example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) on the apache site

```
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("localhost", 443),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
```

The direct link to the java file is http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java

Comment: Right, that's the third step in my solution.  The first two steps are validating that there is an auth requirement (getting `AuthScope` from the response) and displaying the dialog (getting `UsernamePasswordCredentials` from the user).  I'm really interested in if there's an existing implementation of the whole flow or if not, if there are any issues to be addressed within the flow.

Comment: Not a final answer but you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10850182/808940